# Fill missing dates on aggregation on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to aggregate my MongoDB collection. I need to return a query with all the objects with date between the `$min` and `$max` date from the collection. There will be always a single insertion for every inserted date, but not all dates will have an object inserted.

One of the objects in my collection is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8254098341a325bc160d12"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2016-05-18T16:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "ticker" : "abc123"
}
```

For the date that we don't have any record, we should return:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8254098341a325bc160d12"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2016-05-20T16:00:00.000+0000"), // This is a missing date
    "ticker" : "abc123"
}
```

I've already seen these topics [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235027/mongodb-aggregation-output-non-existent-dates) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406944/mongodb-aggreagte-fill-missing-days) but I can't figure it out how to implement the `$map` for my case.

```
db.movs.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$data",
                ticker: { $first: "$ticker" },
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "date_2" : {
                  "$map": {
                  }
                }
            }
        },

    ]
);
```