# Populate JSON query result in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to partially populate search result done with MongoDB.

Search is based on statistics data saved in MongoDB, but within range it may someday not value and need to fill with pair: missing date: zero

Example this result, on 2021-06-23 there is no data, so I need to populate with 2021-06-23.

Is there any way to populate direct when doing the find on MongoDB? Or using Javascript?

[image]

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235027/fill-missing-dates-in-records  or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406944/mongodb-aggreagte-fill-missing-days

Comment: Thanks @R2D2 I used these both posts as reference, but I filled usinf java script.

Answer (score 1):

I filled the data using Java script.

This function return array with the date

```
get__Dates__From__Interval = (startDate, stopDate) => {
    var dateArray = []
    var currentDate = moment(startDate)
    var stopDate = moment(stopDate)
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days')
    }

    return dateArray
}
```

With the array of date I loop and push the date pending

```
 let arrayDate = functions.get__Dates__From__Interval(startDate, endDate);

 var arrayDateLength = arrayDate.length;

   for (var i = 0; i < arrayDateLength; i++) {

      let index = response.findIndex(val => val.date == arrayDate[i]);
      if (index < 0) {
            response.push({ quantity: 0, date: arrayDate[i] });
      }
   }
```

Here I am ordering the array based on date

```
sort__dates = (a, b) => {
    if (a.date < b.date)
        return -1;
    if (a.date > b.date)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

response.sort(functions.sort__dates);

return res.status(200).send({ error: false, response });
```